# Swap CSS background image on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a function that will cause the CSS background image of an element to change to a different image on click. Ideally, a second click would revert the image to the original, and so on.

I've searched this site for similar examples, and I was able to find some close examples, but nothing on the nose. Rather than pasting in some code I've found elsewhere, I'm hoping someone can take a look at my HTML/CSS in the Fiddle below and tell me what I need to do with the jQuery.

HTML:

```
<header id="switch">
    <h1>
        <span>Howie Mandel</span>
    </h1>
    <h2>
        <span>Howie Doin</span> 
    </h2>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4em;
    background-image: url("https://media.timeout.com/images/102596453/image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 10em;
    background-position: bottom;
 }

 header-alt {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4em;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/LA_San_Gabriel_Mountains.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 10em;
    background-position: bottom;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92m4309b/13/)

Comment: did any answer help you out? if so, please mark one as accepted (people spent time on them :D )

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle a class which overrides the standard background image. Take a look.

```js
$('.change').click(() => {
$('#switch').toggleClass('header-alt');
});
```

```css
header {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 4em;
 background-image: url("https://media.timeout.com/images/102596453/image.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 height: 10em;
 background-position: bottom;
 }
  
 .header-alt {
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/LA_San_Gabriel_Mountains.jpg") !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <header id="switch">
   <h1>
    <span>Howie Mandel</span>
   </h1>
   <h2>
    <span>Howie Doin</span> 
   </h2>
  </header>
    <button class="change">
  Change Background
    </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but for whatever reason I'm unable to get it working on my site. No helpful errors in console. Any thoughts?

Comment: Be sure that you are loading jquery script (script tags) in the end.. before closing body. And check that you need to define rule (new background img) for the class „header-alt“ in css.

Answer (score 1):

Use toggleclass with a modifier.

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4em;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 10em;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-image: url("https://media.timeout.com/images/102596453/image.jpg");
}

.alt{
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/LA_San_Gabriel_Mountains.jpg");
}
```

That way you only need a single line of jquery

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  $('header').toggleClass('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
```

you can set up a click event like this

```
$('#divID').on('click', function() {
   ...
   $('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two CSS rules (`header` and `header-alt`), I would use classes lay it out like this:

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4em;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 10em;
  background-position: bottom;
}
header.mandel {
  background-image: url("https://media.timeout.com/images/102596453/image.jpg");
}
header.doin {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/LA_San_Gabriel_Mountains.jpg");
}
```

Start by giving the header in the HTML the class you want to start with (`<header class="mandel">`)

Then you can have jQuery like this:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  $('header').toggleClass('mandel');
  $('header').toggleClass('doin');
});
```

Where your button has the ID button.

Comment: Why would you toggle 2 classes? On every click.. that means : 1. Query the document and find the element, check if the class exists, if not add it. 
And that twice.. not very performant right? :D